# How to tie a model to another model on a specific bone?

Tags: c#, model, xna, game-engine, mesh

I meet a difficulty attached to a model to another model on a "bone" accurate.
I searched several forums but no result. I saw that many people have asked the same question but no real result see no response.
Thread found :

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21129/how-to-attach-two-xna-models-together

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44515/how-can-i-attach-a-model-to-the-bone-of-another-model

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391852/attach-model-xna

But I think it is possible.

Here is my code example attached a "cube" of the hand of my player

```
private void draw_itemActionAttached(Model modelInUse)
    {
        Matrix[] Model1TransfoMatrix = new Matrix[this.player.Model.Bones.Count];
        this.player.Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(Model1TransfoMatrix);
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in modelInUse.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                Matrix model2Transform = Matrix.CreateScale(1f) * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(0, 0, 0);

                effect.World = model2Transform * Model1TransfoMatrix[0]; //root bone index
                effect.View = arcadia.camera.View;
                effect.Projection = arcadia.camera.Projection;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: so you're asking how to parent one model to another?

Comment: Hmm yes. I just want to attach another model (an object, a weapon etc. ..) on another model (a character) on a specific bone (right hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach can vary, but a common way to do this is to add one or more bones to your "equippables", whether they be handheld or not. That way the object's bone(s) can be added to the player's at runtime, thus "equipping" the items at the desired location.

Some reading: http://en.csharp-online.net/XNA_Game_Programming%E2%80%94PlayerWeapon

Comment: Waouhh ! I'm going see your link and i go back for talking result...This link seems to me perfect for my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much friend! Sorry I forgot to answer coming from the time